# Any method to Convert the UserControl to a lite Visual object in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

There is a big Data Collection in my WPF application.To show them ,I bound the collection into a customized `ItemsControl` by using some specific `DataTemplate`. It didn't work well .

I'm haunted by a memento that someone had told me that there is a attached property or something like that in `Canvas` (or other panels? ),which can convert the complex `DataTemplate` (User Control) to some very lite visual objects.Unfortunately,I was too stupid to recall the details.Could you plz give me some hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean the [BitmapCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.bitmapcache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) option